# Targeting a sub ul in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im trying to append some html into a ul (class sportMatches) under the div with the id myEventsContainer, but how can I target it? This does not appear to work:

```
    $(this).parent().parent().appendTo($('#myEventsContainer .sportMatches'));
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you trying to add a new list item or something?

Comment: Uhm, where exactly is `this` coming from, and posting some markup would probably help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a couple of choices

```
$('#myEventsContainer .sportMatches').html('<li>some html</li>');
```

or

```
$('#myEventsContainer .sportMatches').append($('.myhtml'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#myEventsContainer .sportMatches').append($(this).parents('#element'));
```

Instead of .parent().parent() try: `.parents('yourTargetParent')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#myEventsContainer').find('ul.sportMatches').append('<p>Some text</p>');
```